# Django: How to load file not in MEDIA_ROOT correctly | FileField?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.11

In my Django project I have application in which I want to load files NOT in MEDIA_ROOT. I used `storage` attribute to change the place but it raise error.

I used next code but it raise error when I try to load the file. How can I fix this problem?

**settings.py:**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from os import environ

PRODUCT_STORAGE = FileSystemStorage(location=environ.get('PRODUCT_STORAGE_PATH'))

def product_file_upload_path(instance, filename):
    if instance.category=="1":
        path = '/category_1/' + '/%s' % filename
        return path
    elif instance.category=="2":
        path = '/category_2/' + '%s' % filename
        return path
    else:
        path = '%s' % filename
        return path

class Product(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[validate_file_extension],
        storage=PRODUCT_STORAGE,
        upload_to=product_file_upload_path,

    )
```

**ERROR:**

```
The joined path (/category_1/test.pdf) is located outside of the base path component (/other_folder)
```

Comment: I found the problem already. As you said the problem was in slash. Anyway can you post your answer as a post (not like a comment), I will mark it, bro ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the leading slash and use `'category_1/'` and `'category_2/'`.

You'll also want to remove slash from `'/%s'`, otherwise you you'll end up with `//` in the path. You can use `os.path.join()` to prevent mistakes like this.

```
import os
path = os.path.join('category1', filename)
```